# How to get PSSM of protein by protein sequence with python?

Tags: python, psi-blast, pssm

I didn't find way that convert protein sequences in  FASTA to PSSM by python,
and how to write program in python to find PSSM for our data set ?
Maybe better to question how to find PSSM from NCBI alignments ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site. Where did you search? Did you look up to biopython? What is your data set? A collection of fasta sequences or alignments?

Comment: Thank you for your answer , yes i check biopython , but there is no method or class that get protein sequences in fasta and return pssm  . for example from NCBI site , for each sequences.

Comment: Ok, so you want to retrieve from the NCBI site, download the protein sequences and then create a pssm? That is different from what you posted. Please [edit] the question to include this details. Would you be fine with a solution that worked with a local blast program?

Comment: I think better to use psi-blast from NCBI to find my alignments for each sequence  i don't know easy way to  get aligments and pass them to function to get PSSM (i dont know it is necessary to find pssm)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your last comment. What are you trying to do/get? To get a PSSM you need an alignment of sequences. So you need several sequences and then align them (that's what psi-blast does). But you seem to ask about retrieving the PSSM matrix from a psi-blast search. Have you tried something else like hmmer?

Comment: Sorry , i am too beginner . Can you give me  a solution to get PSSM for each of my protein sequence with use psi blast NCBI ? I can calculate PSSM localy on my computer but how to get aligmnets?

Comment: Sorry it is not easy to answer your question. The alignments must be done downloading all the sequences of interest and aligning them via t-coffee or similar tools. Then you can calculate the PSSM matrix (not the other way round)

Comment: @Llopis Thanks, do you know how to automatically download alignments for each protein sequence ?

Comment: Download from where? BLAST perhaps? In what format, and in what language ?

Comment: From NCBI , PSI-BLAST, in xml fomat, in python

Comment: This would require a major re[edit] of the question. Could you please update the question to keep the question and answer related?

Answer (score 1):

We solve our problem and create gitHub repository ([bio-protein](https://github.com/MsAlEhR/bio-protein-recog)).